# In an OpenCL kernel, how to locate the source code line which caused the exception cl::Error at a memory location?

Tags: debugging, exception, parallel-processing, opencl

In an openCL 1.2 program on windows 10, after I enqueue the kernel for several seconds, the prompt shows there is an unhandled exception at a memory location from ucrtbase.dll. So I use "try and catch" to gain more info about the exception. Then I get this:

> Microsoft C++ exception: cl::Error at memory location 0x00000076482F5A28.

There might be a problem with memory read/write in my kernel. But the kernel program contains many lines, so it might be a little hard to read each line to find the wrong lines.
In this situation, How to locate the source code line which might cause this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out parts of the kernel and then run it. At first, comment the lower half of the kernel code. If the error persists, it is located in the upper half (->comment the lower 3/4 of the kernel), if not, in the lower half (->comment the lower 1/4 of the kernel). Repeat this binary search until you arrive at the root of the error.

Comment: Brilliant thinking : ) I never thought I could use binary search to locate the bug before.